# Vue router - API Data not fetching on redirect

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm building an application with JWT Login and i check if the user is logged in (when visit /) and then i redirect to Dashboard:

```
let routes = [
    { path: '', component: Login,
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            if (auth.loggedIn()) {
                next({ path: '/dashboard' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard }
];
```

The Dashboard component is simple:

```
export default {
        created() {
            this.loadOrders();
        },
        methods: {
            loadOrders() {
               // Load Orders
            }
        },
        watch: {
            '$route': 'loadOrders'
        },
    }
```

If i Login, i will be redirected to /dashboard and the data is fetched.

If i'm on Dashboard (`http://localhost:8080/dashboard`) and i hit "refresh" on browser, this works too.

But, if i'm on this url `http://localhost:8080/dashboard` and i delete dashboard (so i just digit `http://localhost:8080`) the `beforeEnter` see that i'm authenticated and redirect me to /dashboard, but **the data is not fetched** (`created`, `mounted` etc are not called).

Comment: I think you should get rid of the this per-route navigation guard `beforeEnter()` and use the global one - `router.beforeEach()`, so It would be triggered on each navigation, but it would be on pending before all hooks has been resolved.

Comment: After login, open a new tab, visit `http://localhost:8080` and see if it works. If it's OK, then maybe your dashboard component is kept alive or reused, only the first visit will trigger `created`.

Answer (score 1):

Why there is no data section on your Dashboard component? If you use some data (ex: loading, error, post) on template, then you need to return them in data section. Try to add that section.

example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading">
      Loading...
    </div>

    <div v-if="!loading">
      {{ error }}
    </div>

    <div>
      <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      post: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData'
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.loading = true
       ...

      this.error = msg;
      this.post = post
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When any action is taken against an API, the server responds with relevant status.
So when you are deleting the product, you have to ignore the response from the server and then push the new path to Vue router.